# How to extract first min value and second min value within a space of time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, min, ranking

I am trying to select customers who have spent amount less than 15 in two consecutive occasions, first purchase must be less than 15, second purchase must be less than 15 and must be 90 days or more after the first purchase. I manage to get those but not able to isolate two consecutive dates with amounts less than 15.

Ideally, only cust1 should appear as my result because even though event on 2010-01-01 violated the rule, another event on 2011-12-18 is preceded by an event that meets the requirement. On the other hand cust2 never had events with amount less than 15 in two consecutive occasions with second date being >= 90 days, so cust2 should not make my list.

#MyList table

| customer | purchasedate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer | purchasedate | amount |
| cust1 | 2008-11-01 | 10 |
| cust1 | 2010-01-01 | 25 |
| cust1 | 2010-12-03 | 30 |
| cust1 | 2010-12-25 | 22 |
| cust1 | 2011-12-18 | 7 |
| cust1 | 2011-12-24 | 11 |
| cust1 | 2014-10-06 | 9 |
| cust2 | 2010-01-01 | 11 |
| cust2 | 2010-02-05 | 25 |
| cust2 | 2013-10-17 | 8 |
| cust2 | 2014-10-28 | 27 |
| cust3 | 2010-01-01 | 6 |
| cust3 | 2011-04-05 | 25 |
| cust3 | 2013-01-01 | 8 |
| cust3 | 2013-02-28 | 5 |
| cust3 | 2013-04-05 | 12 |

My script below

```
   WITH firstevent AS(
   SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT *, 
   row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate ASC) rn
   FROM #MyList 
   WHERE amount < 15) A
   WHERE rn = 1
   ), secondevent AS (
   SELECT * FROM(
   SELECT *, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY purchasedate DESC) rn
   FROM #MyList 
   WHERE amount < 15) B
   WHERE rn = 1
   )
   SELECT f.customer, f.amount AS FirstAmount, s.amount AS LastAmount, f.purchasedate AS Date1, 
   s.purchasedate AS Date2 
   FROM firstevent f
   INNER JOIN secondevent s ON (f.customer = s.customer)
   WHERE DATEDIFF(D, f.purchasedate, s.purchasedate) >= 90
```

Answer (score 2):

use `LAG()` to obtain the previous date and amount and compare

```
select *
from
(
    select *,
           prev_date   = lag(purchasedate) over (partition by customer 
                                                     order by purchasedate),
           prev_amount = lag(amount) over (partition by customer 
                                               order by purchasedate)
    from   #MyList 
) l
where l.amount < 15 
and   l.prev_amount < 15
and   datediff(day, l.prev_date, l.purchasedate) >= 90
```

or using the `row_number()` method, perform a self join and compare

```
with list as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by customer order by purchasedate)
    from   #MyList
) 
select *
from   list l1
       inner join list l2 on l1.customer = l2.customer
                         and l1.rn       = l2.rn - 1
where  l1.amount < 15
and    l2.amount < 15
and    datediff(day, l1.purchasedate, l2.purchasedate) >= 90
```

Comment: Thanks @squirrel, this works but does not take account of - say three consecutive amounts less than 15, date1 and date1 are less than 90 days apart but date1 and date3 are >= 90 days apart, in this case value 2 should be ignored and since value 1 and value 3 are all less than 15 and >= 90 days apart this customer should be selected. Is there a way I can implement this?

Comment: please add such scenario samples data to your question and also include the expected result

Comment: Thank you @Squirrel, I added cust3 who purchased on three consecutive dates with amounts < 15.  2013-01-01 and 2013-02-28 are less than 90 days apart and  2013-02-28 and 2013-04-05 are also less than 90 days apart. since the amount on 2013-02-28 is less than 15 the script should consider 2013-01-01 and 2013-04-05 as valid since they are 90+ days apart and their amounts are < 15. It should only ignore cust3 if the amount on is > 15. Therefore it would be cust1 and cust3 who should pass the conditions. Thanks a lot.